# Facebook Open Graph Debug Issues

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, facebook-sharer

I am trying to use FB's open graph tags, and used https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ to validate my markup.  The results gave me three errors.

```
Inferred Property   The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property   The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
fb:app_id hasn't been included in the meta tags. Specify the app ID so that stories shared to Facebook will be properly attributed to the app. Alternatively, app_id can be set in url when open the share dialog.
```

Here are code snippets from my source.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html,charset=utf-8"/>

<head>
<title>I am Saving For</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" user-scalable="no">
        <meta property="og:title" content="Live Richer">
        <meta property="og:description" content="I Am Saving For">
        <meta property="og:type" content="website">
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="944869545605682">
        <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.livericherchallenge.net/">
        <meta property="og:image" content="http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/5188mjZW9WTa9PQRefM4YEqkH8Ry_ztq6flrPHlrX5zV4eCtnQtsGxpjJtV2pBHQG3S9ANBXLLFtDb-eMIkLVgs=s0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="font/fonts.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.livericherchallenge.net%2F" target="_blank">FACEBOOK</a>
</body>
</html>
```

What is incorrect with my meta tags? I have the url, title, and app_id correctly typed.

Answer (score 0):

However you are loading them doesn't seem to render in the final page.

This is how Facebook sees your page https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.livericherchallenge.net%2F

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>www.livericherchallenge.net</title>
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
<frame src="http://livericher.leadpages.co/live-richer-2016/" frameborder="0">
<frame frameborder="0" noresize>
</frameset>
<!-- pageok --><!-- 04 --><!-- -->
</html>
```

This is how I see it in Chrome view source

view-source:http://www.livericherchallenge.net/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>www.livericherchallenge.net</title>

</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://livericher.leadpages.co/live-richer-2016/" frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 01 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't solve the question of why my meta tags aren't being properly read. Or am I missing a reason here?

Comment: @AngrySpartan You are using something in the background that I don't know about. All I can see is what debugger shows. Your tags are obviously malformed.

Comment: The code you posted is not what I see when I go to that website @AngrySpartan